# How to make a common behavior when a single class needs different structure

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I got some C# classes with a method which creates a string I need. 2 classes does it the same but 1 class does it differently:

```
public class Base 
{
    public abstract bool GetAction(out string res);
}

// There is another class B which does the same
public class A : Base 
{
    public override bool GetAction(out string res)
    {
       ...
       string str1 = some logic to get a string needed
       string str2 = some logic to get another string needed
       res = str1 + str2;
       ...
    }
}

public class C : Base
{
    List<Configs> configs;
    ...

    public override bool GetAction(out string res)
    {
       ...
       for(int i = 0 ; i < configs.size(); i++)
       {
           string str1 = some logic to get string based on configs[i].cfgString;
           string str2 = some logic to get another string based on configs[i].cfgString;
           res = res + configs[i].cfgString + str1 + str2; //immutable string is not the issue here so please ignore it
        }
     }
```

Now there's a need to get the `str1` and `str2` by itself.

I started making a return class instead of the bool of the `GetAction` method like this:

```
public StringsInfoClass
{
    public string Str1 { get; set; }
    public string Str2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string ToString()
    { 
        return Str1 + Str2;
    }
}
```

The problem is that classes A and B has indeed only a single `Str1` and `Str2` while class C can have several of them. And since they are deriving from the same base class, the user will expect the same interface. 
What do you believe a good implementation for this problem here could be?

Comment: It is incredibly hard to give advice with things called `C` and `str1`. Are you able to rename them to more meaningful names? In the meantime, I would suggest making `Str1` an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

So simply and more specifically your question is, you need same return type for method `getAction()`, but class A and B need `StringInfo` as return type, while class C needs it as `List<StringInfo>`.

The solution is using [generics](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics).

```
public class Base<T> 
{
    public abstract T GetAction(out string res);
}

public class A : Base<StringInfo> 
{
   public override StringInfo GetAction(out string res)
   {
      //implementation
   }
}

public class C : Base<List<StringInfo>> 
{
   public override List<StringInfo> GetAction(out string res)
   {
      //implementation
   }
}
```

Finally, If you want to make `StringInfo`, more extensible you may use abstraction for that class. It would help to add different logic for `toString()` methos, if you want different behaviors for that in future.